# How to find parent's child with querySelector instead of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Requirements dictate that I cannot use jQuery and I'm trying to solve the following problem w/out it.

Layout has has identical multiple inputs like this

```
<div class="item">
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="file" />
</div>
<div class="item">
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="file" />
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the javascript needs to find the sibling file input when a textbox is clicked.

```
$('input[type=text]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".item")
        .find('input[type=file]')
        .trigger('click');
});
```

Note: I cannot use Ids because there are multiple (many) "items" on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vanila script event handlers and the next sibling relationship between the elements like

```js
//get all the text input elements which are descendants of .item
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.item input[type="text"]');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  //add click handler
  els[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    //nextElementSibling is supported from IE9
    this.nextElementSibling.click()
    //or
    //this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="file"]').click()
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="file" />
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="file" />
</div>
```

- [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)